# Connect 2 nodes for all materials via python script

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I want to connect 2 nodes for all materials at once.
Specifically the vertex color node with the mix vertex color node

I want to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

For every material.

Any help would be appreciated, not very familliar with python at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John's answer seems to be absolutely correct for how you presented your question. However, if you'd rephrase your question as:

> How do I change each *Vertex Color* output going to a node labelled *"Mix Vertex Color"* to use `Alpha` output instead of `Color`?

Then the best answer I can come up with would be:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes if mat.node_tree else []
    vc_nodes = (n for n in nodes if n.type == 'VERTEX_COLOR')
    for vc, link in ((n, l) for n in vc_nodes for l in n.outputs['Color'].links):
        if link.to_node.label == 'Mix Vertex Color':
            mat.node_tree.links.new(vc.outputs[1], link.to_socket)
            print(f"Changed material {mat.name}")
```

This turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

That is, it iterates over all materials, and then makes sure to change each link from a node of type `VERTEX_COLOR` to a node with a **label** `Mix Vertex Color`, to go from the `Alpha` socket.

### Alternative code

```
import bpy

check = lambda x: x.from_node.type=='VERTEX_COLOR' and x.to_node.label=='Mix Vertex Color'
trees = (m.node_tree for m in bpy.data.materials if m.node_tree)

for tree, l in [(t, l) for t in trees for l in t.links if check(l)]:
    tree.links.new(l.from_node.outputs[1], l.to_socket)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this script:

```
import bpy


for eachMat in bpy.data.materials:
    
    if eachMat.node_tree is not None:
        if eachMat.node_tree.nodes.find("Vertex Color"):
            vertexColor = eachMat.node_tree.nodes["Vertex Color"]
             if eachMat.node_tree.nodes.find("Mix"):
                mix = eachMat.node_tree.nodes["Mix"]
                eachMat.node_tree.links.new(vertexColor.outputs[1], mix.inputs[2])
                print("changed:", eachMat.name)
```

Prerequisite:

Your nodes names must be "Mix" and "Vertex Color".

All changed materials will be printed out.